# How to append data from one MySQL DB to another MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, database, append

Let's say I have two DBs, DB and DB_Replica. When DB is down, DB_Replica will be in use. For other reasons, I'm not able to use HA or whatsoever.

DB_Replica - |--------------------|-----|_____________|

2PM                4PM  4:05PM            6PM

DB               - |____________|-----|---------------------|

Legends;

___ - Data is in

--- - Data is missing

So, in this scenario;

2PM    - Last successful replica of DB.

4PM    - Production DB is down.

4:05PM - Replica of DB is up and data is coming in.

6PM    - Production DB has recovered.

How do I append the 4:05PM to 6PM data from DB_Replica into DB so that the missing data is only from 4PM to 4:05PM?

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSERT INTO statement like this :

```
INSERT INTO newDatabase.table1 (Column1, Column2) 
SELECT column1, column2 FROM oldDatabase.table1;
```

Or you can insert into new database using the command line as:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

Comment: Wouldn't that create a new DB and put whatever's in DB_Replica into a new DB?